# Как правильно составить условие?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не могу разобраться, как правильно составить условие программы. Сам код:

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')

if int(text):
    print('Вы ввели число!')
else:
    print('Вы ввели текст!')
```

Пишу телеграм бот, но конкретно этот кусок кода я не понимаю как сделать.

Если переменная text является int, то работает print.

Но как только боту написать обычный текст, сразу ошибка. Пишет: text не является int().

Помогите...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если переменная text является int

Для приведенного кода это неправильное понимание. Правильно так: **если строку, содержащуюся в text можно преобразовать в целое число**. `int()` превращает строку в число. Если такое невозможно. А если невозможно, то возникает ошибка. Что должно выйти на `int("привет")`? "привет" невозможно преобразовать в число, поэтому и ошибка.

Кстати, если ввести "0", то его можно преобразовать в целое число, но код все равно выдаст "вы ввели текст".

Один из вариантов - использовать try..except.

Comment: Я понял! Спасибо огромное! Через try..except получилось

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант можно через метод isdigit(). Возвращает True, если строка состоит только из цифр.

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')

if text.isdigit():
    print('Вы ввели число!')
else:
    print('Вы ввели текст!')
```

Comment: note: при этом ², ³ итд тоже рассмтриваются как числа.